# I try to read a text file and saved the data in an Arraylist, but the Scanner read methods have an Scanner closed error

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Here is my code, The city is another class which contains three int
 variable. I tried to follow our teachers' instruction, but there is
 this error. I don't know why this happens.

```
public class Test {
  private static List<City> cities;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readFile("res/data.txt");// TODO code application logic here
    }
    public static void readFile(String filename){
     try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
            cities = new ArrayList<City>();
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                cities.add(new City(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextInt(),sc.nextInt()));
              sc.close();
            }          
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to move this line

```
sc.close();
```

outside the while loop so

```
public class Test {
  private static List<City> cities;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readFile("res/data.txt");// TODO code application logic here
    }
    public static void readFile(String filename){
     try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
            cities = new ArrayList<City>();
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                cities.add(new City(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextInt(),sc.nextInt()));
            } 
            sc.close();         
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is obvious error. You are calling `sc.close()` in a loop. So only the first line would be read. You have to move `sc.close()` to after the `while` loop.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Your `sc.close()` call is the last statement **in** the `while` loop. Move it after the `}`. **But**, if there is an exception, your current code leaks a file handle. This is not good. Better to move the `close` call to a finally block. Even better, they added [`try-with-Resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) because that is cumbersome (and correctly handling close is difficult). To use that, it would be something like

```
public static void readFile(String filename){
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filename))) {
        cities = new ArrayList<>(); // Diamond Operator
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            cities.add(new City(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextInt(),sc.nextInt()));
        }          
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move               `sc.close();`
 out of while loop.